# WMS layer can't load - conflict QGIS/PyCharm?

Tags: pyqgis, wms, pycharm

I have been struggling for some days to find a solution.
I wrote a script which work pretty well in the QGIS python console.
This script is using different layer, SHP and WMS.
I am trying to use this script in PyCharm because I want to use PyQgis as a portion of a larger script.

But the code is showing an error while I import a WMS layer.
I got this error:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

The portion of my code which isn't working is :

```
*"urlWithParams = contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=SCAN_D_GEOL50&styles&url=http://geoservices.brgm.fr/geologie"

rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'MAP', 'wms')

if not rlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
map = QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)"*
```

I did setup the python interpreter in PyCharm as python-qgis.bat which is showing :

```
*@echo off
call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%
python %**
```

I also tried this solution (https://plugins.qgis.org/planet/tag/pycharm/) which isn't working.

Now I don't know what to do. Because this portion of script is working on QGIS Python console but not working on PyCharm.

Comment: How did you set up your QGIS application and QGIS project?

Comment: I have QGIS at :
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.3

Comment: I meant in the Python script that is failing.

Comment: I have choosen the "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.3\bin\python-qgis.bat" as the python interpreter, as we can see is this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7srHXlRqJk

Then, in the script, I used 
from qgis.core import *

Comment: Note the layer is scale layered `<MinScaleDenominator>9000</MinScaleDenominator>
<MaxScaleDenominator>251000</MaxScaleDenominator>`  so you may get an error if make a request outside of the range, depending on how exceptions are handled

Comment: @nmtoken . This should not be a problem because the exact same code is working good in the Qgis python console. The wms layer is loading. But it does not in Pycharm. That's why it should be a problem of setup or conflict ...